# Null pointer assignment error union

Tags: c, pointers, null, variable-assignment, unions

in the above code i cannot enter the name of student as it gives a null pointer assignment error. how to resolve this , i can enter the roll no and it displays the result just fine

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
union student
{
    int roll_no;
    char name[10];
}s1,*a;
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    *a=s1;
    printf("Enter roll_no : ");
    scanf("%d",a->roll_no);
    clrscr();
    printf("Roll No : %d",a->roll_no);
    getch();
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter name : ");
    scanf("%s",a->name);
    clrscr();
    printf("Name : %s",a->name);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use a `union` rather than a `struct`?

Comment: @Bathsheba you are spot on, a union does not make sense.

Comment: `*a=s1;` doesn't make sense either and will likely cause the program to crash

Answer (score 4):

```
  *a=s1;
```

Change this to -

```
  a=&s1;
```

And this statement-

```
scanf("%d",a->roll_no);     // %d expects address of int variable
```

should be -

```
scanf("%d",&a->roll_no);
```

***Note-*** - `void main()` **->** `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Turbo C dislikes `int main` ;)

Comment: @AlterMann Then probably its time for OP to say Good Bye !!  to Turbo C :-)

Comment: @AlterMann No, Turbo C accepted `int main` just fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. The line

   ```
   *a = s1;
   ```

   copies `s1` to the memory `a` is pointing to, although you didn't allocate any memory.

   I think your actual intent was to load `a` with the address of `s1`:

   ```
   a = &s1;
   ```
2. You need to provide the **address** of an object to `scanf` to read from `stdin`:

   ```
   scanf("%d",&a->roll_no);
   ```
3. The line

   ```
   scanf("%s",a->name);
   ```

   may cause a buffer overflow because it reads any string, no matter which length. Write

   ```
   scanf("%9s", a->name);
   ```

   to be safe, or better, use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
4. `void main()` is no strictly-conforming definition of `main`. If your system allows it, OK, but otherwise that should be `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.